# php login redirect header failure and javascript redirect workaround failure

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, header

This is the first time I've worked with php, and I've been working on a login for a website using a form that uses POST for username and password. I have the connection and credential checking working, but every attempt I have made for redirecting after that has failed. I've read many similar questions on here, but even after going through many of them here I have been unable to get header() to work or using a javascript echo function to work. I've been looking to see if it was a white space problem like many here have been, but have been unable to find that. I also read about the issue about the header already being posted, or sending info before the header is hit but I've tried variations to check for that but have been unable to get past this problem.

```
<?php
include ("dbconnection.php");
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$password'";
    $returned = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    //$entry = mysqli_fetch_array($returned,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //$active = $entry['active'];

    $matches = mysqli_num_rows($returned);
    if ($matches==1) {
        //$error = "Login Accepted";
        //header("Location: calendar.php");
        session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$user;
        //mysqli_close($conn);
        //exit;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 
        'location.replace("calendar.php");',
        '</script>';
        //header("Location: calendar.php");
    }else{
        $error = "Invalid UserName or Password";
    }
    //echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 
    //  'check();',
    //  '</script>';
} 
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <title>Login Page</title>      
      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }         
         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }         
         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>      
   </head>  
   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function Register(){
        window.location.assign('register.php');
    }
    function check(){
        var message = document.getElementById('error').textContent;
        //textContent = message.textContent;
        var a = "Login Accepted";
        var b = "Invalid UserName or Password";
        var n1 = message.localeCompare(a);
        var n2 = message.localeCompare(b);
        if (n1 == 0) {
            alert('Login Accepted!');
            window.location.assign('calendar.php');
            //exit;
        }
        if (n2 == 0) {
            alert('Invalid UerName or Password')
        }
    }
   </script>
    <br>
    <br>
      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>         
            <div style = "margin:30px">               
               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/>
                  <input type = "button" value = " Register " onclick="Register()" /><br />
               </form>               
               <div id='error' style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>                 
            </div>              
         </div>         
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"every attempt I have made for redirecting after that has failed"_ in what way? Are you getting the _"headers already sent"_ error, some other error? An error in javascript?

Comment: Since there is a session_start ( ); on top of the file, and a couple of line further, header ( ) he is indeed getting the Header already sent. Use ob_start(); before the include dbconnection.php for a quick fix.

Comment: The url never changes, and the screen goes blank. I also get this in the console:  The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I've tried checking the meta tags and they seem correct. I've tried them a few ways to be sure.